# Using Celery to queue tasks with pre-specified thread concurrency?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, celery

I'm looking at using Celery in a project to queue scientific computing tasks on a server.  Most often, the tasks will be single-threaded, single-processor tasks, but there are several packages that we commonly use that can take as a parameter a number of threads to use.  Thus we can specify the concurrency ahead of time when we create the tasks.

I would like to configure Celery so that workers can take into account both their concurrency and the number of threads required by the tasks.  For example, if a worker has concurrency 10, and it takes on a task requiring concurrency 6, then the worker will know that it only has "capacity" 4 remaining to take on other tasks.  Moreover, a worker will only attempt to take on this task if its concurrency exceeds 6.

Is there a nice clean way to do this?  Is there a not-so-nice and dirty way to do it?